# Where do I put '$ npm install $ npm develop' on my local machine

Tags: node.js

I am trying to input this:

```
$ npm install
$ npm run develop
```

in my local machine. When I try to put this on my Windows Powershell, I get an error. In particular, an error with `$`. What should I do? Thank you.

Comment: you should not be entering in the `$`

Answer (score 1):

`$` is just a character that indicates you are using CLI (Command Line Interface) and don't put it in execution command.

Just do each of single commands below:

```
npm install
npm run develop
```

Comment: To clarify further, each line is its own command. Hit enter after entering each in your terminal.

Comment: `$` shows the commands are for Linux/Ubuntu. Without `$` you can run it in windows also!